# How to restrict decompilation of .xap file

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, c#-3.0

I have built an application for windows phone 8 .I am using visual studio 2015 version .Now I do not want my source code to be recovered from .xap file.
There are two options which will work me.

1. If I able to restrict de-compilation of my .xap file
2. Even if code gets de-compiled my .xaml.cs and .cs files should NOT be in readable format.

Answer (score 0):

To cover point 2. look at code obfuscators.

Wikipedia has a [list of .NET obfuscation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET) (but it's marked as being "considered for deletion").

However, ultimately you are fighting how the system works with xap files so your options are limited.